Why the PMSM FOC control current loop sampling appears negative value?
I ported the code of simple FOC 1.6, and then wrote the current sampling code myself. When I used the current open-loop control, I set Uq = 0.5, but the sampled iq was about -0.3 when the motor was rotating, and about -0.5 when the motor was stalled. Why was it negative?
This is my code:
void Current_sensor::park_transform(float angle)
{
    float sinAngle = arm_sin_f32(angle);
    float cosAngle = arm_cos_f32(angle);

    Id = cosAngle * alpha + sinAngle * beta;
    Iq = -sinAngle * alpha + cosAngle * beta;
}

void Current_sensor::clarke_transform(float Ua, float Ub)
{
     alpha = Ua;
     beta = (Ua + 2 * Ub) * 0.57735027f;
}

The code call:
roll_current_sensor->clarke_transform(roll_current_sensor->Ia, roll_current_sensor->Ib);
roll_current_sensor->park_transform(roll_foc->rotor_flux_angle_read());

